# Unable to seed users and roles after a new database is created in .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-5, seed

Once the database is created I am unable to get the users and roles to seed.
I am using a multi-tenancy app that needs to create a database first and then seed the user and roles.

I do not get any error messages. The code completes however nothing is put into the database.

Main api

```
public class systemController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo; 


    public systemController(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, 
        RoleManager<Role> roleManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IMapper mapper, IUserRepository repo)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repo = repo;


    }
    //create the new database
    [HttpGet("CreateNewDb/{dbName}")]
    public ActionResult CreateNewDb(string dbName)
    {           
        var __roleManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
        var __userManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        string serverDataString = "server=localhost; user=user; password=password; database=";
        
        // this method works and created the database
        createDb(dbName, serverDataString);

        // this method does not work
        createUserRole(dbName, serverDataString, __roleManager, __userManager);
    }
```

createUserRole method

```
    private static void createUserRole(string dbName, string serverDataString, RoleManager<Role> __roleManager, UserManager<User> __userManager)
    {
        var connectionString = serverDataString.Replace("database=", "database=" + dbName);

        // build a DbContext for this tenant 
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseMySql(connectionString, 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));

        DataContext context = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        Seed.SeedRoles(context, __roleManager);   
        Seed.SeedUsers(context, __userManager);
    }
```

role in seed class

```
public class Seed
{     
    public static void SeedRoles(DataContext context, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any())
        {
            //create roles
            var roles = new List<Role>
            {
                new Role{Name = "Admin"},
                new Role{Name = "Standard"}, 
                new Role{Name = "Basic"} 
            };
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Wait();                    
            }  
        }
                         
    }
```

Comment: The `UserManager<>` and `RoleManager<>` classes have a `DbContext` instance injected by the dependency injection container. Creating a separate `DbContext` instance with a different connection string will not affect the `DbContext` instance used by those classes.

Comment: Is there any way to change the UserManager<> and RoleManager<> after the injection? I have tried with a new API where the new URL with the database name newDB.localhost:5000 allows it to seed the role and users. however, when I deploy it I get a cors error. i want to be able to do it all within the same api.

Comment: Where do you savechanges on dbcontext ? You should call await db.SaveChangesAsync(); after createasnyc method call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GolfBravo after you change data context , you have to eventually call SaveChanges method on context in order to commit changes of context to database. There isn't any information about how you do it. I think basically you have to to call context.SaveChangesAsync() at end of foreach loop.

Comment: I added the context.SaveChangesAsync() to the end of the roles loop however it still does not save. I have a feeling that its something to do with the RoleManager<> being incorrect. I believe it gets the information from startup.cs when the api is initially hit.

Comment: @GolfBravo There is no information about what RoleManager class do, If you add your roles to context in RoleManager class than why you need an extra context instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might  don't add your roles to context and/or you don't commit changes in a right way. You can just do like this ,

```
public class Seed
{     
  public static async Task SeedRoles(DataContext context)
  {
      if (!context.Roles.Any())
      {
          //create roles
          var roles = new List<Role>
          {
             new Role{Name = "Admin"},
             new Role{Name = "Standard"}, 
             new Role{Name = "Basic"} 
          };
         
         context.AddRange(roles);
         await  context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
                     
}
```